# Paypal REST API with PHP SDK - How to get the transaction number?

Tags: php, rest, api, paypal, sdk

I'm using the REST API Paypal ExpressCheckout with the PHP SDK, my script is able to process payment but I would like to get a essential information about the payment : the transaction number, usefull for tracking payment.

He's anybody no how to get the transaction number after a payment ?

I use the version 1.

I've tried to do this :

```
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
$payment->getTransactions()[0]->getRelatedResources()[0]->getSale()->getId();
```

The returned result does not match with the transaction number.

I've also tried to do this :

```
$payment->getTransactions()[0]->getInvoiceNumber();
```

That returns NULL.

I've tried many object and methods of the API without finding the solution.

Thankz by advance for your help,

Mickaël

Answer (score 1):

With v1/payments, when you execute the payment there will be a transactions->sale->id

With v2/checkout/orders, when you capture an order there will be a payments->captures->id

Comment: I've not found the properties "transactions->sale->id" in the "payment" object.
Can you please add some code sample ?

I've tried "$payment->getTransactions()[0]->getRelatedResources()[0]->getSale()->getId()" without success.

Please check the code sample that I've add in my first post.

Comment: "The returned result does not match with the transaction number"

It should match. Note that the receiver and sender's transaction #s are different

Comment: That's OK, I wanted to get the custumer transaction Id, but it's appear to be not possible. However, the seller transaction id can be found by doing $payment->getTransactions()[0]->getRelatedResources()[0]->getSale()->getId()"